# Linearly Interpolating Data with Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I'm new to Pandas, and I'm having trouble with interpolating Series data.

I have some CSV data that looks like:

```
ts = pd.Series(L2.values, time)
        t                  L2
    0   1480438222797   9.7861227923056670618962016306
    1   1480438222817   9.7861227923056670618962016306
    2   1480438222838   9.7861227923056670618962016306
    3   1480438222858   9.7861227923056670618962016306
    4   1480438222877   9.7861227923056670618962016306
    ....
```

I want to change the time intervals to 20ms intervals, and linearly interpolate the L2 of the new rs time intervals, based on the old ts L2 data.
Using Pandas, and I have tried:

```
rs = ts.resample('20ms').mean()
```

which successfully gets the time into the proper interval format. I then try

```
rs = rs.interpolate(method='time')
```

to interpolate the data, but the L2 values of "rs" end up being the exact same as the original "ts" ones.

I found this to be the solution for a couple other people on Stackoverflow, but it's not working for me so I'm not sure why. Any help would really be appreciated! :)

Comment: Your sample data is all the same.  So interpolating it will result in all of the same values.

Comment: Ah, sorry, this data is not representative of what I'm working with. I'm working with hundreds of thousands of lines, and rs.equals(ts) == true.